# Image size browser height - X number of pixels. CSS-only!

Tags: css, image

I'm looking for a CSS-only solution, to shrink an image to the size of the browser window - X amount of pixels. I've found quite a lot JavaScript solutions, but I want to make it CSS-only. Can it be done and if yes, then how?

Comment: What's wrong [with this](http://jsfiddle.net/bqbGY/)?

Comment: Putting it into a container with a 200px right margin should be the right approach

Comment: Why does it HAVE to be a css only solution?

Comment: @Pekka Where does the "200px" come from?

Comment: @w3d well, whatever "x amount of pixels" is supposed to be

Comment: @Loktar why create a Javascript dependency for this?

Comment: heh good point @Pekka should of posted that as an answer.

Comment: @Pekka ah, ok... reducing the size _by_ x amount of pixels? The original question appears to suggest that the actual width (in pixels) of the browser window is reqd - not possible in CSS alone. I would have thought the only solution should feature `width:100%` if the image is to be shrunk "to the size of the browser window"? Any additional margins will result in the image being **smaller** than the browser window? Hhhmmmm, what does the OP have to say...?

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/mXSTQ/)

**HTML:**

```
<div><img src="http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png" /></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 30px;
    right: 30px
}
img {
    width: 100%
}
```

Comment: Why the `position: absolute`? Shouldn't be necessary. Doesn't `margin-right: 100px` work?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/mXSTQ/1/ (Edit: mmm, well almost, if you go below 100px width, the image will reset to original size it seems. Maybe needs some more fine-tuning.)

Comment: @thirty your solution behaves better with extremely small sizes, though. Shrinking the browser window shows the difference

Comment: Another good point about mine is that the background will already be behind *stuff*: http://jsfiddle.net/mXSTQ/3/

Comment: @Pekka Did you fine tune it already? It appears to work OK for me below 100px in Firefox (Win).

Answer (score 1):

```
img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Tada!! :)

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/bqbGY/

EDIT:

```
div {
    left: 0px;
    margin: 15px;
    position: absolute;
}
img {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Where the margin property on the div is x pixels.
Obviously, this means wrapping you img in a div.
Like so:

```
<div>
    <img src="" />
</div>
```

Edit again: Just a note, instead of using the `margin` property, you could use separate `margin-left` and `margin-right` properties. :)

Comment: You missed the ' - X ' amount of pixels part.

Comment: @david: The what part? Edit: nevermind, I see. In the original question.

Comment: I agree about missing the -x pixels, but with it having to be a css only solution I think this is the best bet. The OP can just change it to 98%, 45% etc.

Comment: I misunderstood what that meant. I'll be right back with a second answer that includes it.

Comment: @Loktar `98%` does not equal `(100% - a defined amount of pixels)`, not by a long shot

Comment: Yup I know. Thats why I put best bet, rather than the final solution :P

Comment: @david I hoped so. Every time I answer a CSS question I get down voted for no reason. I'm just trying to help. xD